# switching between multiple URLs in HTML/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

Below is an example of what I would like but it has two flaws currently.

1. I believe that the order is incorrect because I cannot see any url sites beyond google.com.  Something must be off in the location of certain items in the code.  I have tried it without pop-up blockers and still cannot get the other windows to show.
2. I believe that this program is supposed to open in different windows/tabs.  I would like mine to open the next url in the same window and tab and replace the original.

   - Google replaced by msn; msn replaced by yahoo

I am grateful for the help.  Thank you everyone.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var urlList = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.msn.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url

function openWindow(){
    wnd = window.open(urlList[curIndex], '', '');
    setTimeout(function () {
         wnd.close(); //close current window
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); //open the next window if the array isn't at the end
    }, 2000);
}

openWindow();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI. Your doctype should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` for the html5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reuse your window instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlList = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.msn.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url

function openWindow(){
    wnd = wnd || window.open();
    wnd.location.href = urlList[curIndex];
    setTimeout(function () {
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         // If all urls have been showed, close our window instance
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); else wnd.close();
    }, 2000);
}

openWindow();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for your solution. Thanks

Comment: select code -> `[ctrl]+[c]` -> `[ctrl]+[alt]+[j]` (opens your console) -> `[ctrl]+[v]` -> `[enter]` -> see the magic unfold.

Comment: I guess he would want to write it in the js file, not in console

Comment: @Fyre It will yield the same result as running code in the console will be run under the same privileges as running code embedded on the current page.

Comment: I think i have misunderstood the question. He stated that it should open in the same tab, whereas in your solution its opening in a new tab.

Comment: Do remember this will first open a new tab and then change in that tab

Comment: @Fyre If you read the question you will see that OP says: ' I have tried it without pop-up blockers and still cannot get the other windows to show.' which clearly states that (s)he is working with popups

Comment: if you read the second point it says:' believe that this program is supposed to open in different windows/tabs. I would like mine to open the next url in the same window and tab and replace the original.' which i think means that he wants to open in the same tab. I may be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you open in the same page your javascript will be gone. It won't work. As soon as google.com is opened that will be the end of your javascript. So you should open in either a new tab or consider using iframes.

See here for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: This is not true, you can still change the location of the window. But you cannot communicate with the content of the window.

Comment: how can you do that? when you open a new page the javascript is gone. Please enlighten me

Comment: `var my_window = window.open('https://google.com'); /*....*/ my_window.location.href = 'https://example.com'`

Comment: when google.com is opened. do you still have your javascript?. How is your  update going to work.

Comment: You can still reset the location object, thats all i know.

Comment: i dont think so. As soon as a different page is loaded, the js is loaded again, in this case an external url like google.com where the OP's js wont be avaiable and hence it wont work. Can you provide a fiddle for your solution?

Comment: Instead of assuming you could test it: `var my_window = window.open('https://google.com'); setTimeout(function() {my_window.location.href = 'https://example.com'}, 5000);`

Comment: @dev-null I am new to this and do not know where I should be putting this line of code.  Could you either provide how the code would need to be set in my example or explain where I should be putting this line and what new variables I need?  Thank you.